# How do I get the href content of a video with seleniun inside an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, video, iframe, href

I have a problem wanting to get the content of a href that has a video. I got to enter the page and click on the video, the href appears on the page once I click on the video, until I click on the video I get, but then I can't get to the href.

This is the code of the page

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIvt1.png)

The code is longer and the href is inside an iframe but honestly I don't know how to copy the text from the html so I sent the image .. I want to get the content of the href as the iagen shows, but it didn't get there. That content appears when I click on the video. Next I leave my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time, re, requests

algo = "Player YouTube"
driver.get("https://www.supertelevisionhd.net/dragon-ball-z-en-vivo/")
time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='post-100']/div/center/iframe"))
time.sleep(1)
click1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="{}"]'.format(algo))
time.sleep(5)
click1.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '/html/body/iframe')))
time.sleep(5)
enlace = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected((By.CLASS_NAME,'html5-vpl_title_l vpl-antialiased')))
print(enlace)
```

This is the error I get

```
> File "C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\pruebas driver.py", line 36, in <module>
> enlace = WebDriverWait(driver,
> 10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected((By.CLASS_NAME,'html5-vpl_title_l
> vpl-antialiased'))) File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
> line 71, in until value = method(self._driver) File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py",
> line 329, in call return self.element.is_selected() AttributeError:
> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_selected'
```

I would appreciate any help. I repeat, what I want to obtain is the content of href, that is, what http: //ok.ru says ...

Thanks

Comment: where is `is_selected` in your code ? I do not see that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much English, I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are passing a `tuple` instead of an `element` in the last before line.

Change the last before line in your code to this:

```
enlace = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected(By.CLASS_NAME,'html5-vpl_title_l vpl-antialiased'))
```

You added an extra paranthesis () and therefore the error.

Comment: Now I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\PRUEBA\SELENIUM\PRUEBAS\pruebas driver.py", line 45, in <module>
    enlace = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_selected(By.CLASS_NAME,'html5-vpl_title_l vpl-antialiased'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given